# srand(time(0)) and random number generation

Tags: c++, random

```
srand(time(0))
```

is used in C++ to help in the generation of random numbers by seeding rand with a starting value.

But, can you explain what it exactly does?

Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`srand()` gives the random function a new seed, a starting point (usually random numbers are calculated by taking the previous number (or the seed) and then do many operations on that number to generate the next).

`time(0)` gives the time in seconds since the Unix epoch, which is a pretty good "unpredictable" seed (you're guaranteed your seed will be the same only once, unless you start your program multiple times within the same second).

Comment: Whether it's "pretty good unpredictable" depends on an attacker's means. If it's possibly to guess when the random number was generated, the space of possible seed values might be pretty short. So this is *not* a way to generate cryptographically secure random numbers. But srand/rand is not suitable for this anyway...

Comment: When you say: "time(0) gives the time in seconds...", what do you mean here? Can you just give an example of the output? Thanks.

Comment: The Unix epoch is 1 January 1970 00:00:00. `time(0)` returns the amount of seconds that have passed since that moment.

Comment: "time(0) returns the amount of seconds that have passed since that moment.". But, shouldn't as you said I get the time in seconds? For example, today is 19th January 2011. What should I expect time(0) to return for me? In other words, say it is 19th January 2011 5:04 PM, what will time(0) give me (roughly)? Thanks.

Comment: +1 for the "unless you start your program multiple times within the same second", I sranded(time(NULL)) multiple times within a second => hence always same random numbers :D

Answer (score 4):

From what I remember, there is an equation that is used to generate a sequence of values. The next value is somewhat influenced by the previous value. By using the time, you are setting the initial value of the equation. Keep in mind, the values are pseudo random.

So for example, if you do something like this:

```
srand(1);
srand(1);
```

The same sequence of numbers will be generated. However, if you do:

```
srand(time(0));
srand(time(0) + 1);
```

Two different sequences of numbers will b e generated because the seed value is different.

Comment: @user489041: Only if you do the two `srand(time(0))` with a one-second gap in the middle of them.

Comment: In the last example, not really different unless there's more than 1 second between two `srand` calls. That holds if you have `srand(time(0))` once at the beginning of the application and you run it many times per second (some scripting approaches, for example). May be surprising sometimes.

Comment: @Tomalak Gert'kal @Kos- Agreed, that was a nasty bug I had to find one time. In the example, the lines will probably execute much faster than one second apart. Updated answer.

Comment: @user489041: You might as well just have written `srand(1); srand(2);` now. :P You should also mention that it's usually wrong to call `srand` more than once in a program; your answer may imply to a language newcomer that he ought to `srand` every second.

Comment: @Tomalak Agreed, I would never recommend the code for actual production. Just to show a point that the initial value influences the sequence of numbers.

Answer (score 3):

The C `rand` function generates random numbers using a seed (just like most -- any? -- pseudo-random generator).

`srand` is used to set the seed to be used by the random generator algorithm. The value returned by `time` (ie: the current second) is usually passed to such function because it's the most simple-to-get value that is usually different between two executions of an application

Answer (score 3):

firstly, `srand` & `rand` is for/from C, not C++, C++0x is introducing its own [random number generator classes](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2079.pdf).

Other than that `srand` & `rand` are implementation defined, they only need deliver a random between 0 and `RAND_MAX`. On [windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/398ax69y%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) its a basic [MWC16/32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply-with-carry_%28random_number_generator%29), that uses TLS to store seeds, `srand` sets that seed, which is then used by `rand` to roll a pseudo random number.

By way of random number generators its pretty terrible, especially the windows version.

Comment: +1 Good point about security. Also note that at least in ISO C RAND_MAX may be as small as 32,768, so it only provides 15 bits of randomness, even if you use a perfectly random seed...

Answer (score 2):

There's an [article at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) that gives some good history and examples of algorithms used.

The short version is that `rand()` and its ilk are pseudorandom number generators.  In fact, they're actually deterministic—the sequence of numbers produced is always the same.  However, the sequence is very very long, and the seeding mechanism provides a means of starting at a (more or less) arbitrary place in that sequence.

Depending on how the random numbers will be used, there are a variety of criteria for evaluating the quality of a pseudorandom generator. In very simple circumstances, perhaps all that's needed is a low probability of repeated values from consecutive calls to `rand()`.  However, you're likely to want the numbers to conform to a particular statistical distribution as well.  (As far as I know, most PRNGs produce uniformly distributed numbers. However various functions exist or can be easily written to transform this into a gaussian distribution or any other you might need.)

Finally, when security is a concern, you want an algorithm that is, for all practical purposes, unpredictable.  If an attacker knows the previously generated number, she shouldn't be able to then anticipate the next.  In very high security applications, a truly random number generator might be used; these would rely on various external sources of randomness, such as radio static, the thermal noise in an image capture device (lens cap on), or other such sources.  Also, many modern operating systems (including Linux) gather and store an "entropy pool" from various sources such as unpredictable user interactions and allow the production of random numbers from that.

A common programming error from people not used to working with pseudorandom generators is to re-seed before every call to `rand()`.  Of course, this is unnecessary and probably undesirable.  Seed each generator only once.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include "stdio.h" //rmv coding for srand is pure
#include "conio.h"
#include "time.h"

void main()
{

    time_t t;

    srand(time(0));

    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) 
        cout << (unsigned) rand() % 1000 - 90 << "\t";

    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        cout << (char) rand() % 100 - 90 << "\t";

    getch();

}
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, nor is it valid C++ Code.