# srand(time(0)) not making random numbers?

Tags: c++, random, srand

Here is the code, but the outputs aren't coming out random? Maybe cause when the program runs it has the same time as all the loops?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>


int main()
{
    long int x = 0;
    bool repeat = true;
    srand( time(0));

    int r1 = 2 + rand() % (11 - 2);     //has a range of 2-10
    int r3 = rand();

    for (int i = 0; i <5; i++)
    {
        cout << r1 << endl;          //loops 5 times but the numbers are all the same
        cout << r3 << endl;          // is it cause when the program is run all the times are 
    }                                // the same?
}
```

Comment: why use srand(time(0)) in c++ ?

Comment: You are not changing the values `r1` and `r3` inside your loop.

Comment: @NeilKirk because c++ provides. std::default_random_engine and others sophisticated class.

Comment: I think you are confused about how the assignment operator and expressions work. You are not assigning or binding the expression to the variable, you are assigning the _result_ of the expression to it.

Comment: @deeiip That is C++11, which he may not be using.

Comment: @NeilKirk, There's still Boost.Random.

Comment: @NeilKirk It is tagged C++. If they don't have C++11, they should specify that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [srand(time(0)) and random number generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736485/srandtime0-and-random-number-generation)

Answer (score 4):

You need to move your calls to `rand()` to inside your loop:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>


int main()
{
    long int x = 0;
    bool repeat = true;
    srand( time(0));


    for (int i = 0; i <5; i++)
    {
        int r1 = 2 + rand() % (11 - 2);     //has a range of 2-10
        int r3 = rand();

        cout << r1 << endl;          //loops 5 times but the numbers are all the same
        cout << r3 << endl;          // is it cause when the program is run all the times are 
    }                                // the same?
}
```

That said: since you're writing C++, you really want to use the new random number generation classes added in C++ 11 rather than using `srand`/`rand` at all.

Comment: The cppreference.com page is: [Pseudo-random number generation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)

Answer (score 1):

You must call `rand()` each loop iteration.

```
for (int i = 0; i <5; i++)
{
    cout << 2 + rand() % (11 - 2) << endl;    
    cout << rand() << endl;          
}
```

What was happening before was that you were calling `rand()` twice, one for `r1` and once for `r3`, and then simply printing the result 5 times.