# Is it possible to predict random number of srand(time(0))?

Tags: c++

my rand number is rand()%6+1 aka dice rolling, when its based on "time", is it possible to make a console app that foresees the future numbers in the time I want to? for example predict a  number on time 14:40:32 on a certain day in future?

Comment: Maybe you got [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4736527/2050745) here.

Comment: If you're programming in C++, `#include <random>` and forget about `rand()`.

Comment: [Real world use case for that](https://labs.bitdefender.com/2015/11/linux-ransomware-debut-fails-on-predictable-encryption-key/).

Comment: See also http://taeb-nethack.blogspot.com/2009/03/predicting-and-controlling-nethacks.html .  tldr: selected good times to start up the game nethack so that it would be guaranteed a very rare item on level 1.

Answer (score 1):

Yes provided that you use the same implementation of `rand` i.e. link with the same version of the standard library. All you need is to get the `time_t` value for the time you are interested in pass it to `srand` and call `rand` to get the value.

For example, if `time_t` holds the number of seconds since the epoch (which is the case for most implementations), then you can do the following to get the value returned by `rand` with a 10-second-in-the-future seed:

```
std::srand(std::time(nullptr) + 10);
std::cout << std::rand();
```

(Leaving aside the questions of whether it's a good idea to use `rand` at all.)

Comment: how to make a console app that shows me all random numbers in like future +10 sec with the time? example 14:48:53 Number: 3, 14:48:54 Number: 5 and so on

Comment: @Sick654: Easy. You normally call `srand` with the `time` value, but nothing prohibits you from calling `srand` with `time()+10`

Comment: okay I got it, but how to make a loop that shows me every second on console first the predicted time and next to it the random number?

Comment: @Sick654 : By typing in the instructions needed. Pick up a C++ book if you need help with that.

Answer (score 0):

> ... for example predict a number on time 14:40:32 on a certain day in future?

It's possible when knowing how exactly `rand()` generates the pseudo random number on a certain seed (which is available for most compilers open source code implementation).

You have a certain seed number given from your date and time, thus you can just inspect the sequence of random numbers generated consecutively.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. *If* you have a value of `time_t`, then just run the same library version of `srand()` on that value, and `rand()` will definitely yield the same sequence.

But you need to be sure that

- the random libraries in the two applications use the same implementation (I think it's Mersenne Twister, but I'd need to check)
- the clock of the two applications is synchronised. If you *think* that the master application's clock is 14:30:17, but it's really 14:30:18, then entering 14:30:17 in the monitor application will (of course) get different values.
- the sequence of calls to `rand()` in both applications is the same, i.e., the number of calls between the srand() and the rand() you are interested in is known by you.

The last point might be a showstopper.

Say that you know that the app was initialised with srand(T) and you know T. Now yes, you know all the future extractions of its rand(). But you still need to know at which point in the sequence you are.

The number extracted at 19:30:17 GMT will not depend on the '19:30:17 GMT', but on how many numbers have been extracted before since the call to srand().

**TL;DR** if you know the value that time(0) passed to srand(), you cannot predict the output of the rand() call at a given *time*. You can predict the output of the n-th call to rand() for any given *n*.

Comment: The normal `rand` in glibc is not Mersenne Twister. But the point, is of course, that there are only so many random number generators that are in common C libraries, so it's not very hard to guess on one of them [or try all three or four].