# Predict random number from someone elses PC?

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography

Well assuming someone else is using the same method to generate a random number.. I would like to generate the same number as them and predict it.

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int min;
    int sec;
    int hour;
    int x;

    srand(time(0)+10);


    for(;;)    
    {
         x=time(0)+10;
         sec= x%60;
         min= x/60 % 60;
         hour= x/60 /60 % 12+1;

         cout<<hour;
         cout<<":"<<min;
         cout<<":"<<sec;
         cout<<" Number: ";
         cout<<rand()%6+1<<endl;
         Sleep(1000);    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

this should show me on console every 1 sec new numbers which will be random in 10 sec.. am I doing something wrong? if yes, how could I predict someones number when I know some of the random numbers on certain times (when I make like 100 tests every 20 seconds and see what number they generate)?

Comment: When you say "using the same method", do you _also_ mean "using the same method for seeding the random number generator" (in addition to the obvious "using the same random number generation algorithm")?  Because you can seed the generator with anything you like.  Using `time(0)` is the ultimate lazy approach, and is insecure for the exact reasons that caused you to write this question.  Also, it's possible that `rand` is mapped onto a hardware number generator, in which case prediction is very unlikely.

Comment: You asked the same question a few hours ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35420847 and you have 3 answers. Perhaps your problem is converting `time_t` to date/time in standard format